# Firebase jobdispatcher перестаёт работать после 5 минут

Tags: android, firebase

Проблема следующая:

Firebase Job Dispatcher перестаёт работать через минут 5 после закрытия приложения.

У меня стоит периодическое выполнение задания.

Почему Firebase Job Dispatcher умирает примерно через минут 5?

```
public void onStartJob(){
    Job job=firebaseJobDispatcher.newJobBuilder().
            setService(MyJobService.class).
            setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER).
            setRecurring(true).
            setTag(JOB_TAG).
            setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(10,10)).
            setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL).
            setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK).
            setReplaceCurrent(false).build();
    firebaseJobDispatcher.mustSchedule(job);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"JobSheduled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```